# HTC Desire 816- how do I turn on my mobile data?

Tags: data-connection, mobile-data, htc-desire-816-dual

I have been relying on my WiFi due to not knowing how to connect to my mobile data. When i turn my mobile data on, the switch turns green indicating that it is on however, it says disconnected underneath and the mobile data doesn't work.
Please help, Thank you.

Comment: Added info -->  phone was shipped in from China and had the language changed back to English. I am not sure if by it being foreign makes a difference since everything else on the phone works fine.

Comment: Have you set up the APN information for your carrier?